# Movie controller obscured in QTMovieView when movie is made editable for 10.7+

Tags: macos, osx-lion, quicktime

When running with OS X 10.7 or newer, the cursor area in the QTMovieView controller becomes completely black whenever the QTMovie is made editable.  As such, there is no visible cursor, and selections are not indicated.  Same code running on 10.6.8 or older works fine.  If the "editable" attribute is not set, the cursor is shown as expected.

Yes, I've looked at AVFoundation, but I need to handle any format QT can handle, which is a lot more than AVFoundation supports.

To be sure I hadn't introduced something in my code, I've started from scratch, following the Apple Dev docs for setting up a simple editable movie view, and the result is always the same.  Here's the example I was following:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/ExtendingMediaPlayerApplication/ExtendingMediaPlayerApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH5-SW1

This example outlines setting up a basic application with QTKit and putting a QTMovieView in a window and loading a movie file to play, then making it editable.  To make the movie editable, I followed the example:

```
    - (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
    {
        QTMovie *newMovie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:absoluteURL error:outError];
        if (newMovie) {
            [newMovie setAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieEditableAttribute];
            [self setMovie:newMovie];

        }
        return (newMovie != nil);
    }
```

To test this, commenting out the `setAttribute` line makes the cursor visible, but of course the video is not editable.

I've tried this with Xcode/Interface Builder versions from 3.2.6 to 4.6 with the same results.  I've tried 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 SDKs.  An app built on 10.6.8 with 10.6 SDK runs on 10.7+. Playback is fine, but it exhibits the controller issue.  Building with newer SDK's does not change this.  This appears to be a runtime issue.

No errors are reported.

Has anyone else see this?  Is there a known work-around?  The only possible solution that I've come up with is to build a custom controller.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the QTMovieEditableAttribute = NO when the player is playing, you'll see the slider thumb.

The movie doesn't care how many times you change the attribute, as long as it's YES when you try to make an edit.

It's easier to make a couple of #defines like EDIT_ON and EDIT_OFF to set the QTMovieEditableAttribute - I find that helps to bracket my editing code clearly...